# synchronizing servers time using calendar class injava

Tags: java, web-services, calendar

I have constructed two servers in web service using java.My problem is that i couldn't figure out how can i synchronize servers time using calendar class in java.I would be glad if you help me with that, at least it would be nice to give me an example how can i do that.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that you should use Java to sync the system times between them. There is a matured and widely spread protocol available for this issue: [The Network Time Protocol](http://www.ntp.org/)

Otherwise you have to deal with

- network latency
- time drifts of internal CMOS clock
- getting the correct reference date
- system rights: normally root is required to change the time ... and you don't want your web service running as root?

Of course, all of these issues is solved in NTP.

Comment: Thanks for replying but i need to do it especially with calendar

Comment: It's not possible with `Calendar` itself. The class would only be a small (and nearly irrelevant) piece of code in the whole protocol you have to implement.