# Clock synchronization between servers using Sockets on Java

Tags: java, web-services, sockets

I need to synch my servers that i built by using web service on java using Sockets.Can you give me any suggestions how to do that?I am planning to use Symmetric Time Model but even though i know the logic of it, i couldnt implement it.

THanks

Comment: I would take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10863752/758280) on your last question. It really is the best option for you to take.

Comment: Asking a question more than once, doesn't make it more likely that you'll get an answer - less likely actually *goes deleting his halve finished post*

Comment: possible duplicate of [synchronizing servers time using calendar class injava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863718/synchronizing-servers-time-using-calendar-class-injava)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- The best idea (IMO) is to deploy (or configure) NTP on the servers and synchronize them all to a reliable network time source.  See the answers to your previous question!
- If you do *have to* implement your own time synchronization, you'll need to figure out how to implement some time model.  Asking someone else how to do it is not going to help, because it is not something that people do.  (Why would they bother?  NTP does the job ...)
- The simpler alternative is to set up a simple server on one of the machines (designated the "time master" or "time lord" or something), that tells a client what its time clock says.  Then the clients just get the time from the client, and set their clock to it.  (The snag is that things can go wrong if the "time lord" machine's clock drifts or if gets set to a bogus value somehow.)